# Initializing reference types outside of a function in Actionscript 2

Tags: arrays, initialization, actionscript-2

I have this small class called City that simply holds some information about a city, here it is:

```
class com.weatherwidget.City {
    var zipCode:String;
    var forecastText:Array = new Array(5);
}
```

When I have an array of cities and I change one of the forecastText of one city it will change that forecastText for all of the cities.

For example:

```
import com.weatherwidget.City;

var arr:Array = new Array();
arr.push(new City());
arr.push(new City());

arr[0].forecastText[0] = "Cloudy";
trace(arr[0].forecastText[0]);
trace(arr[1].forecastText[0]);
```

Will have the following output:

```
Cloudy
Cloudy
```

Even though I only changed arr[0].forecastText[0]. I think I must be misunderstanding something about arrays in objects for actionscript 2.

Comment: If anyone can suggest a better question name for this question please let me know.

Comment: The accepted answer explains why this happens, and my answer makes it work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the reason why ... hmmm ... little complicated to explain ...

alright ... ActionScript is [prototype-oriented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-oriented_programming), as is ECMA-script ... classes are only a syntactic sugar introduced by actionscript 2 (this has changed yet again in as3, but that's a different subject) ...

so if this is the original code:

```
class com.weatherwidget.City {
    var zipCode:String;
    var forecastText:Array = new Array(5);
}
```

then this is, what actually happens:

```
//all classes get stuffed into _global, with packages being a property path:
if (_global.com == undefined) _global.com = {};
if (_global.com.weatherwidget == undefined) _global.com.weatherwidget = {};
//and the actual definition:
_global.com.weatherwidget.City = function () {};
_global.com.weatherwidget.City.prototype = { forecastText:new Array(5) }
```

the prototype object of `City`, that serves as prototype for instances of `City`, has a property called `forecastText`, which is an `Array` of length 5 ... so when looking up `forecastText` on an instance of `City`, it cannot be found directly and will be looked up in the prototype chain ... it will be found in the instance's prototype ... thus, all instances share the same `Array` ...

the difference is, that the second example gets translated to:

```
//same thing here:
if (_global.com == undefined) _global.com = {};
if (_global.com.weatherwidget == undefined) _global.com.weatherwidget = {};
//and the actual definition this time:
_global.com.weatherwidget.City = function () { this.forecastText = new Array(5); };
_global.com.weatherwidget.City.prototype = {}
```

as you might have noticed, declared members are only a compiletime thing ... if nothing is assigned to them, they simply will not exist at runtime ...

well, this explenation requires, that you either know JavaScript or ActionScript 1 a little, but i hope it helps ...

greetz

back2dos

Comment: There is an excellent book called "Object-Oriented Programming with ActionScript" (http://tinyurl.com/m6s7bn) by Branden Hall (who also hangs out on StackOverflow) that explains all of this in very great detail.

Answer (score 1):

The array needs to be initialized inside of a constructor for some reason or all the City objects will point to the same array. So the city class should look like:

```
class com.weatherwidget.City {
    var zipCode:String;
    var forecastIcons:Array;

    function City() {
        forecastIcons = new Array(5);
    }
}
```

I still don't know why it must be initialized in a constructor since the array isn't static, so if anyone would like to explain this that would be much appreciated.